# How to covert tab separated file to CSV file

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I have a tab separated text file which is about 1.2 GB , i need to convert it into CSV file(Comma Separated) using c#.
I have to insert a bulk data into sqlserver, the data is in txt file, which is tab separated, but i want it to convert into CSV first and then insert into sql server or is there any suitable way to insert the tab separated data into sql server database efficiently.

Comment: Have you considered using Integration Services to import the data?

Comment: @WadhawanVishal - Just read the contents of the file and create a new file using commas to seperate the values instead of tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Import the tab separated file into Excel (or another spreadsheet program) then export it as CSV.

Comment: This is a good "outside of the box" answer.  The only other alternative is to read the entire file, and save a new file, using commas into of tabs, to seperate the values.

Answer (score 1):

The BULK INSERT command in SQL Server 2005 will use a tab as a field delimiter by default so there is no need to convert a tab delimited text file to csv format.

In fact, converting it to a real csv will make things more difficult. BULK INSERT will not respect quotes as a string delimiter so a true csv file that has strings encapsulated by quotes with commas somewhere in the string will break the import.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(v=sql.90).aspx for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sqlserver, you should have a look at SSIS (SqlServer integration Services). This tool will help you to import your csv file in a efficent manner. You can configure your seperator in this tool, so there is no need to replace the tabs with comma's.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this which splits on the tab character:

```
   using(System.IO.StreamReader rdr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\text.txt"))
   {
            int counter = 0;
            string lne;
            while((lne = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] temp = lne.Split('\t');
                Console.WriteLine(temp[0]);
                Console.WriteLine(temp[1]);
                counter++;
            }
   }
   Console.ReadLine();
```

After that you can just use a StringBuilder to concatenate the the items in the array with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

If its SQl Server 2005 and above, right click the database you want to import to and select **Tasks** and then **Import Data**. Point to your tab delimited file and just go through the remaining screens. On the final screen, just before you actually import, you have an option to save it as a **SSIS package**(check box). This is by far the easiest, fast and efficient way (without the conversion from tab delimited to csv) to import it without writing any code and the code is also available at the end of the wizard, which can be used to automate the task, if required.