# Convert a tab delimited file into CSV file in c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to covert tab separated file to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605451/how-to-covert-tab-separated-file-to-csv-file)

i have a tab delimited text file which i have to convert into CSV file all this must be done through C# code. My txt file is very large about(1.5 GB), hence i want to convert it in a quick time. please help me.

Comment: feel the wrath of  http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I've seen you asked a couple other questions but have not had much luck getting a lot of answers.  Please check out the [FAQ] and [this link](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) has a good blog entry one of our leading members wrote on how to ask good questions.

Comment: Does your input (the tab delimited text file) contain any commas (,) or quotes(")?  If so, you might need a more complicated method to replace them tabs with commas without breaking the output file.

Comment: As @LukeHennerley mentions, there are a lot of SO questions that answer this already.
Take a look at:
[How to Convert a Tab Separated File To CSV Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590631/how-to-convert-a-tab-separated-file-to-csv-format?rq=1)
and [How to Convert a Tab Separated File To CSV File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605451/how-to-covert-tab-separated-file-to-csv-file)

Answer (score 6):

If your input tab delimited text file does not have any commas are part of the data, then it is a very straightforward find and replace similar to the other answers here:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var csv= lines.Select(row => string.Join(",", row.Split('\t')));
File.WriteAllLines(path, csv);
```

But if your data has commas, doing this is going to break your columns as you now have extra commas that are not supposed to be delimiters, but will be interpreted as such.  How to handle it depends greatly on what you application you will be using to read the CSV.

A Microsoft Excel compatible CSV is going to have double quotes around fields with commas to make sure they are interpreted as data and not a delimiter.  This also means that fields that contain double quotes as data will need special treatment.

I would recommend a similar approach with an extension method.

```
var input = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var lines = input.Select(row => row.Split('\t'));
lines = lines.Select(row => row.Select(field => field.EscapeCsvField(',', '"')).ToArray());
var csv = lines.Select(row => string.Join(",", row));
File.WriteAllLines(path, csv.ToArray());
```

And here's the EscapeCsvField extension method:

```
static class Extension
{
    public static String EscapeCsvField(this String source, Char delimiter, Char escapeChar)
    {
        if (source.Contains(delimiter) || source.Contains(escapeChar))
            return String.Format("{0}{1}{0}", escapeChar, source);

        return source;
    }
}
```

Also, if the file is large, it might be best to not read the entire file into memory.  In that case, I would suggest writing the CSV output to a different file and then you could use `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` to only work with it 1 line at a time.

```
var tabPath = path;
var csvPath = Path.Combine(
                Path.GetDirectoryName(path), 
                String.Format("{0}.{1}", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path), "csv"));

using (var sr = new StreamReader(tabPath))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(csvPath, false))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = sr.ReadLine().Split('\t').Select(field => field.EscapeCsvField(',', '"')).ToArray();
        var csv = String.Join(",", line);
        sw.WriteLine(csv);
    }
}

File.Delete(tabPath);
```

Comment: good answer.. This one should get a check

Answer (score 1):

If the format of your file is strict, you could use `string.Split` and `string.Join`:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var newLines = lines.Select(l => string.Join(",", l.Split('\t')));
File.WriteAllLines(path, newLines);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var csv = File.ReadAllLines("Path").Select(line => line.Replace("\t", ","));
```

You could simply call

```
public void ConvertToCSV(string strPath, string strOutput)
{
  File.WriteAllLines(strOutput, File.ReadAllLines("Path").Select(line => line.Replace("\t", ",")));
}
```

There is a lot of content already on SO for handling .CSV files, please search first or trying something.